# Corresponding Coefficients in Python SymPy Pattern Matching

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function named f = 0.5/(z-3). I would like to know what would the coefficients p and q be if f was written in the following form: q/(1-p*z) but unfortunately sympy match function returns None. Am I doing something wrong? or what is the right way of doing something like this?
Here is the code:

```
z = symbols('z')
p, q = Wild('p'), Wild('q')
print (0.5/(z-3)).match(q/(1-p*z))
```

EDIT:
My expected answer is: q=-1/6 and p = 1/3

One way of course is

```
p, q = symbols('p q')
f = 0.5/(z-3)
print solve(f - q/(1-p*z), p, q,rational=True)
```

But I don't know how to do that in pattern matching, or if it's capable of doing something like this.

Thanks in Advance =)

Comment: `q/(1-p*z)` is equal to `(q/p)/(1/p-z)` if `p != 0`. And `(0.5/(z-3)).match((q/p)/(1/p-z), old=True)` returns `{q_: -0.166666666666667, p_: 1/3}`. I don't know how to find this transformation algorithmically though.

Comment: Using `solve` seems like a good method to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you start by converting to linear form,

```
1 / (2*z - 6) == q / (1 - p*z)
                               # multiply both sides
                               #   by (2*z - 6) * (1 - p*z)
1 - p*z == q * (2*z - 6)
```

then

```
from sympy import Eq, solve, symbols, Wild 

z   = symbols("z")
p,q = symbols("p q", cls=Wild)

solve(Eq(1 - p*z, q*(2*z - 6)), (p,q))
```

gives

```
{p_: 1/3, q_: -1/6}
```

as expected.

**Edit:** I found a slightly different approach:

1. `solve(Eq(f, g))` is equivalent to `solve(f - g)` (implicitly ==0)
2. We can reduce `f - g` like `simplify(f - g)`, but by default it doesn't do anything because the resulting equation is more than 1.7 times longer than the original (default value for `ratio` argument).
   If we specify a higher ratio, like `simplify(f - g, ratio=5)`, we get

   ```
   >>> simplify(1/(2*z-6) - q/(1-p*z), ratio=5)
   (z*p_ + 2*q_*(z - 3) - 1)/(2*(z - 3)*(z*p_ - 1))
   ```
3. This is now in a form the solver will deal with:

   ```
   >>> solve(_, (p,q))
   {p_: 1/3, q_: -1/6}
   ```

Comment: Isn't it the same solution I've mentioned in the question?

Comment: @AhmadSiavosh: I reformatted the equations before plugging them into the solver, converting them from nonlinear to linear (in terms of z). This is enough to let the solver deal with them and return a symbolic rather than numeric answer. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to make it do this simplification automatically, but I'm still reading ;-).

Answer (score 1):

SymPy's pattern matcher only does minimal algebraic manipulation to match things. It doesn't match in this case because there is no 1 in the denominator. It would be better to match against `a/(b + c*z)` and manipulate `a`, `b`, and `c` into the `p` and `q`. `solve` can show you the exact formula:

```
In [7]: solve(Eq(a/(b + c*z), q/(1 - p*z)), (q, p))
Out[7]:
⎧   -c      a⎫
⎨p: ───, q: ─⎬
⎩    b      b⎭
```

Finally, it's always a good idea to use `exclude` when constructing Wild object, like `Wild('a', exclude=[z])`. Otherwise you can get unexpected behavior like

```
In [11]: a, b = Wild('a'), Wild('b')

In [12]: S(2).match(a + b*z)
Out[12]:
⎧         2⎫
⎨a: 0, b: ─⎬
⎩         z⎭
```

which is technically correct, but probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, the part about 'exclude' helped a lot.